# how to fix this error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'results')"

Tags: javascript, node.js, typeerror, node-modules

I tried changing the variable, but the results imported using naver api were delivered properly and are not used. How should I deliver the results to click_ratio_json...?

The calling method is a code that when a specific search term is entered in the terminal, the search term is delivered to naver api and the result is calculated and then printed out

The first code is the code that delivers and calculates, and the second code is the code that calls

How do I get the getRatio() function to return information from storage?

```
const request = require("request");
const client_id = "";
const client_secret = "";
const axios = require("axios");
const path = require("path");
const api_url = "https://openapi.naver.com/v1/datalab/search";
const account = require("./account");
const crypto = require("crypto");
const qs = require("querystring");

async function getRatios(keyword, date, device = "") {
  console.log("keyword: ", keyword);
  console.log("device: ", device);
  let request_body = {
    startDate: date[0],
    endDate: date[1],
    timeUnit: "month",
    keywordGroups: [
      {
        groupName: "KW",
        keywords: [keyword],
      },
    ],
    device: device,
  };
  let option = {
    method: "POST",
    uri: api_url,
    body: JSON.stringify(request_body),
    headers: {
      "X-Naver-Client-Id": client_id,
      "X-Naver-Client-Secret": client_secret,
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  };
  request(api_url, option, (error, response, body) => {
    console.log("####", error);
    let storage = response.body;
    console.log("storage : ", storage);
  });
  //결과값을 storage라는 변수에 할당
}

//trends API를 하나의 함수로 묶어 처리
async function getCnt(keyword, date) {
  console.log("getCnt:", keyword);
  const path = "/keywordstool";
  const timestamp = new Date().getTime();
  const msg = `${timestamp}.GET.${path}`;
  const signature = crypto
    .createHmac("SHA256", account.secretKey)
    .update(msg)
    .digest("base64");
  const option = {
    method: "get",
    url: `https://api.searchad.naver.com${path}`,
    params: {
      format: "json",
      hintKeywords: keyword,
    },
    headers: {
      "X-Timestamp": timestamp,
      "X-Customer": account.customerId,
      "X-API-KEY": account.accessLicense,
      "X-Signature": signature,
    },
  };
  return await axios(option);
}
//광고 API를 하나의 function으로 묶어 처리
function pad(n, width) {
  n = n + "";
  return n.length >= width ? n : new Array(width - n.length + 1).join("0") + n;
}
//숫자를 특정 너비로 표현할때 사용
//========================================================================================

module.exports = {
  //위 두 API를 module.export를 사용해 외부로 전송
  async getTrend(keyword, date) {
    let click_ratio_json = await getRatios(keyword, date);
    //click_ratio_json 변수에 trends API의 결과값을 저장
    let info = await getCnt(keyword, date);
    //info 변수에 광고 API의 결과값 저장
    let data = info.data.keywordList[0];
    click_info = [data.monthlyPcQcCnt, data.monthlyMobileQcCnt];
    click_info[0] = click_info[0] == "< 10" ? 0 : click_info[0];
    click_info[1] = click_info[1] == "< 10" ? 0 : click_info[1];
    click_total = click_info[0] + click_info[1];

    console.log("click_ratio : ", click_ratio_json.results[0].data);
    console.log("click_total : ", click_total);

    let per_ratio =
      click_total / int(click_ratio_json.results[0].data[12]["ratio"]);

    let click_trend = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++)
      click_trend.push(
        Math.ceil(click_ratio_json.results[0].data[i]["ratio"] * per_ratio)
      );
    return click_trend;
  },

  async getTrends(keyword, date, device) {
    let click_ratio_json;
    if (device === "total") click_ratio_json = await getRatios(keyword, date);
    else if (device === "pc")
      click_ratio_json = await getRatios(keyword, date, "pc");
    else if (device === "mobile")
      click_ratio_json = await getRatios(keyword, date, "mo");

    console.log("finish");
    let info = await getCnt(keyword, date);
    let data = info.data.keywordList[0];
    click_info = [data.monthlyPcQcCnt, data.monthlyMobileQcCnt];
    click_info[0] = click_info[0] == "< 10" ? 0 : click_info[0];
    click_info[1] = click_info[1] == "< 10" ? 0 : click_info[1];

    console.log("click_info : ", click_info);
    if (device === "total") click_total = click_info[0] + click_info[1];
    else if (device == "pc") click_total = click_info[0];
    else if (device == "mobile") click_total = click_info[1];

    //console.log("click_ratio : ", device, click_ratio_json.results[0].data);
    console.log("click_ratio : ", device, click_ratio_json);
    console.log("click_total : ", device, click_total);

    let per_ratio = click_total / click_ratio_json.results[0].data[11]["ratio"];
    console.log("per_ratio : ", per_ratio);
    let click_trend = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++)
      click_trend.push(
        Math.ceil(click_ratio_json.results[0].data[i]["ratio"] * per_ratio)
      );
    console.log("=========================");
    return click_trend;
  },
  getDate(term = "1y") {
    let today = new Date();
    let before = new Date();
    before.setYear(today.getFullYear() - 1);
    let today_f =
      today.getFullYear() +
      "-" +
      pad(today.getMonth() + 1, 2) +
      "-" +
      pad(today.getDate(), 2);
    let before_f =
      before.getFullYear() +
      "-" +
      pad(before.getMonth() + 1, 2) +
      "-" +
      pad(before.getDate(), 2);

    let today2_f =
      today.getFullYear() + "-" + pad(today.getMonth() + 1, 2) + "-" + "01";
    return [before_f, today_f, today2_f];
  },
};
```

```
const request = require("request-promise");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const readline = require("readline");
const qs = require("querystring");
const express = require("express");
const asyncify = require("express-asyncify");
const app = asyncify(express());
const { getTrends } = require("./Final");
const Final = require("./Final");
const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
});

function main() {
  rl.question("검색할 키워드 입력: ", async (keyword) => {
    const date = Final.getDate();
    const trend_pc = await Final.getTrends(keyword, date, (device = "pc"));
    const trend_mobile = await Final.getTrends(
      keyword,
      date,
      (device = "mobile")
    );
    const trend_total = await Final.getTrends(
      keyword,
      date,
      (device = "total")
    );
    const trends = [trend_pc, trend_mobile, trend_total];
    console.log("trends : ", trends);
    const storage = await Final.getTrend(keyword, date);
    console.log(storage);
    rl.close();
  });
}

main();
```

```
검색할 키워드 입력: 르세라핌
keyword:  르세라핌
device:  pc
finish
getCnt: 르세라핌
#### null
storage :  {"startDate":"2022-07-01","endDate":"2023-07-24","timeUnit":"month","results":[{"title":"KW","keywords":["르세라핌"],"data":[{"period":"2022-07-01","ratio":58.32918},{"period":"2022-08-01","ratio":40.44566},{"period":"2022-09-01","ratio":31.57056},{"period":"2022-10-01","ratio":82.45108},{"period":"2022-11-01","ratio":96.51934},{"period":"2022-12-01","ratio":72.88413},{"period":"2023-01-01","ratio":62.13085},{"period":"2023-02-01","ratio":46.23942},{"period":"2023-03-01","ratio":37.40186},{"period":"2023-04-01","ratio":50.34722},{"period":"2023-05-01","ratio":100},{"period":"2023-06-01","ratio":54.98443},{"period":"2023-07-01","ratio":41.89345}]}]}
click_info :  [ 86500, 451500 ]
click_ratio :  pc undefined
click_total :  pc 86500
C:\Users:134
    let per_ratio = click_total / click_ratio_json.results[0].data[11]["ratio"];
                                                   ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'results')
    at Object.getTrends (C:\Users:134:52)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async C:\Users:19:22
```

When I print out the results, it comes out as follows, but I want to print out the results in storage by delivering only the necessary parts to click_ratio_json
I only need to get the information of the period and the ratio from the results

Comment: Your `getRatios()` function doesn't return anything which is why `click_ratio_json` is undefined

Comment: The `return json` statement is commented out in `getRatios()`. What do you expect it to return?